# Shorten an || or if statement in Golang

Tags: go, shorthand

Learning Golang and was wondering if there is a shorter way to write this

```
            if tiletype == 0 || tiletype == 2 {
                levelmap[passage1block] = "wall"
            } else {
                levelmap[passage1block] = "floor"
            }
```

Was thinking this would be the way though it does not work

```
                if tiletype ==0,2 {
            levelmap[passage1block] = "wall"
            } else {
                levelmap[passage1block] = "floor"
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a switch-case statement:

```
switch tiletype {
   case 0,2: levelmap[passage1block]="wall"
   default: levelmap[passage1block]="floor"
}
```